# angular directive interceptor click event

Tags: angular, angular8

i want Directive click event cancel

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[shortConfirm]'
})
export class ShortConfirmDirective implements OnInit{
  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  public onClick(event: any): boolean {
    console.info('2222');
    event.cancelBubble=true;// ie下
    event.stopPropagation();
    return true;
  }
}
```

I tried event. Cancelbubble = true;

event cancel fail

Answer (score 2):

You can try to intercept event during capture phase and cancel it.

Try this.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[shortConfirm]'
})
export class ShortConfirmDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _elementRef: ElementRef,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    fromEvent(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', {
      capture: true,
    }).subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => {

      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this is fail, element click event first execution,  e.stopImmediatePropagation(); is last execution